# Change the style of one dynamically created LinkButton while not affecting others?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method that loops through a list and creates Links using the LinkButton control.  For the purpose of this question, assume that it is a list of colors and that I have 5 colors: red, green, blue, red, and yellow.  Here is a code snippet of how I am creating the links and adding the event handler.

```
foreach(color in colors)
{
    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
    lb.Text = color.name;
    lb.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.colorClick); 
    lb.CommandName = "CommandName";
    lb.CommandArgument = "CommandArgument";
    lb.ID = color.Id;
}
```

In the even handler, colorClick, I am bolding the clicked link by doing the following:

```
protected void colorClick(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)o;
    lnk.Style["font-weight"] = "bold";

    //Process clicked link.
}
```

The above code works fine as far as bolding the currently clicked link, the problem I run into is that assume that the link clicked was Red, so Red would be bold, if I click Blue, I want to bold the link Blue, but unbold Red.  I have tried:

```
lnk.Style["font-weight"] = "normal";
lnk.Font.Bold = "false";
```

but, it occured to me that while the above maybe correct, I am doing it in the wrong spot (colorClick).  What I was thinking is that I probably have to remember the previously clicked link and unbold that one, but I am unsure of how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got three options:

1. Store the link that was previously bold and un-bold it.

   Iterate the links and look for the one link that's bold and un-bold it.

   Or just un-bold everything before setting the link to bold.

The code to remove font-weight is:

```
lnk.Style.Remove("font-weight")
```

Comment: I tried unbolding eveything, but that doesn't seem to work.  I don't know how to remember the previously clicked link.